# I cant find the lowest AVG in a 2D array! (Highest AVG Works)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im having trouble finding the lowest avg in a 2D array, finding the highest AVG works but i get garbage data when finding the lowest.
Here is my function:
Ive tried making lowest = highest after i find highest but that didnt fix the solution. I know the problem might be in the lowest is initialized at [0][[0] so you cant find a value less than [0][0]. any help?

```
void averaging(double gpa [][NUM_QTRS], double gpa2[][QTR_NUM])
 {
double highest, lowest;
double totalAvg = 0;

highest = gpa2[0][0];
lowest = gpa2[0][0];

for (int stu = 0; stu < NUM_STUDENTS; stu++)
{
    double total = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    double temp;


    // sum up all gpas for 1 student
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_QTRS; i++)
    {
        total = total + gpa[stu][i];

    }

    // calculate average gpa for 1 student
    avg = total / NUM_QTRS;


    //fill second row with GPA of each student

    gpa2[0][stu] = stu + 1;
    gpa2[1][stu] = avg;

    if(gpa2 [1][stu] > highest)
        {
            highest = gpa2[1][stu];
        }
    if(gpa2 [1][stu] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = gpa2[1][stu];
        }


    /*for (int z = 0; z < NUM_STUDENTS; z++)
    {

    }*/



    totalAvg = totalAvg + avg;
    //temp = (static_cast<int>( (avg + 0.005) * 100 ) ) / 100.0;


    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << setw(3) << stu+1 << setw(13) << avg << endl;
}



totalAvg = totalAvg / NUM_STUDENTS;
cout << "Avg of all students: " << totalAvg << endl;
cout << "Highest GPA: " << highest << endl;
cout << "Lowest GPA: " << lowest << endl;
```

} `

Comment: What exactly are you doing in `gpa2[0][stu] = stu + 1;` and `gpa2[1][stu] = avg;`? I'm assuming `NUM_QTR` is the same as `QTR_NUM`? If so, isn't the second dimension in `gpa2` for the quarter and not the student id `stu`?

Comment: for gpa2[0][stu] im storing the student numbers into the first row of a seperate 2d array which is 2X12. and in gpa2[1][stu] im storing all the avg of the students into the second row of the 2d array.
No NUM_QTR has 5 indexes while QTR_NUM has 13 indexes.

Comment: Try initializing lowest with a high value (e.g. 10.0) and highest with a low value (ex. -10.0)

Comment: i dont think i can do that since im working with a 2d array i initialized it at different indexes  though, still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

try to assume that your first student have the lowest AVG
and then run your loop on all the student from the second one

i fixed your code, have a look:

```
void averaging(double gpa [][NUM_QTRS], double gpa2[][QTR_NUM])
 {
double highest, lowest;
double totalAvg = 0;

highest = gpa2[0][0];

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_QTRS; i++)
    {
        total = total + gpa[0][i];

    }

    // calculate average gpa for 1 student
    avg = total / NUM_QTRS;


    //fill second row with GPA of each student

    gpa2[0][0] = 1;
    gpa2[1][0] = avg;

lowest = avg;

for (int stu = 1; stu < NUM_STUDENTS; stu++)
{
    double total = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    double temp;


    // sum up all gpas for 1 student
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_QTRS; i++)
    {
        total = total + gpa[stu][i];

    }

    // calculate average gpa for 1 student
    avg = total / NUM_QTRS;


    //fill second row with GPA of each student

    gpa2[0][stu] = stu + 1;
    gpa2[1][stu] = avg;

    if(gpa2 [1][stu] > highest)
        {
            highest = gpa2[1][stu];
        }
    if(gpa2 [1][stu] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = gpa2[1][stu];
        }


    /*for (int z = 0; z < NUM_STUDENTS; z++)
    {

    }*/



    totalAvg = totalAvg + avg;
    //temp = (static_cast<int>( (avg + 0.005) * 100 ) ) / 100.0;


    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << setw(3) << stu+1 << setw(13) << avg << endl;
}



totalAvg = totalAvg / NUM_STUDENTS;
cout << "Avg of all students: " << totalAvg << endl;
cout << "Highest GPA: " << highest << endl;
cout << "Lowest GPA: " << lowest << endl;
} `
```